# Running a code line several times with saving the results

Tags: r

I've got this line of code. How can I run this code 60 times so that the number at Output.range+1 is increased by 1 after each run. After the sixtieth run there should be +60. Additionally, each run should be stored in a separate df or at least in the same df but with a suitable column name. Would be really really nice if someone could give me some input.

If you need more background or data, just let me know!

Thank you for your help!

Selina1

```
getReturn <- function(corn_test) {
  
  
  num.rows <- nrow(corn_test)
  
  output.range <- 1:(num.rows-1)
  

  
  sell.price  <- corn_test[output.range,2:ncol(corn_test)]
  buy.price <- corn_test[output.range+1,2:ncol(corn_test)]
  
  returns <- data.frame(log(sell.price) - log(buy.price))
  returns <- cbind(corn_test[output.range,],returns)
 
  
  return(returns)
  
}
return<-getReturn(corn_test)
head(return)
```

Comment: Add an argument to the function, e.g. function(corn_test, idx) and adjust the body of the function to use idx instead of 1. Then `out <- lapply(1:60, function(x) getReturn(corn_test, x))`. The object `out` will be a list with 60 data frames.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It works perfectly. But why I have to add within      lapply the function --> function(x) ? What is the idea behind it? Why not function(idx)?

Comment: It could be `idx` as long as you replace both x's. The name is not important, only the fact that it is the second argument in the `getReturn` function.

Comment: Dear dcarlson, I have another question and before I open a new "Question" I ask you. I've got this line of code # Define the function
f_minus <- function(first_col, other_col) {
  
  other_col - first_col
  
}

df_output <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=ncol(df), nrow=nrow(df))) 

for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  
  df_output[,i] <- f_minus(df[,1], df[,i])
  
}

df_output    ; All columns are subtracted by column one df[,1], but how can I do it, that all columns also get subtracted by column2, 3, 4 and until the last column in the df. I'm not able to get it done. Selina1

Comment: This is a distinctly different question. You should open a new question. Include reproducible data using `dput(df)` to provide the matrix.